# Working with Multiline Texts on imagettftext

Tags: php, gd, imagettftext

My code is here, Im trying to create png widget for a website. I do correct others but when im trying to fit my long text in to my cards 181*312 px

I must fit my text in to text area, and its impossible to change my widget sizes

[image: Example Widget.]

So how can wrap my text?

```
            $kartquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM status");
    While($kartqueryyaz=mysql_fetch_array($kartquery)){

// Q & A
    $id                     = $kartqueryyaz['id'];
    $longdesc         = $kartqueryyaz['longdesc'];
    $correct                = $kartqueryyaz['correct'];
    $wrong1             = $kartqueryyaz['wrong1'];
    $wrong2             = $kartqueryyaz['wrong2'];
    $wrong3             = $kartqueryyaz['wrong3'];
    $wrong4             = $kartqueryyaz['wrong4'];






  // carttype
  $png_image = imagecreatefrompng('card1.png');
  // Text Color #white ffffff
  $white = imagecolorallocate($png_image, 255, 255, 255);
  // Font
  $font_path = 'GothamBook.ttf';
  $font_pathdogru = 'GothamRoundedBold.ttf';







  imagettftext($png_image, 25, 0, 55, 230, $white, $font_path, $longdesc);
  imagettftext($png_image, 25, 0, 150, 730, $white, $font_pathdogru, $correct);
  imagettftext($png_image, 25, 0, 150, 850, $white, $font_path, $wrong1);
  imagettftext($png_image, 25, 0, 150, 970, $white, $font_path, $wrong2);
  imagettftext($png_image, 25, 0, 150, 1100, $white, $font_path, $wrong3);
  imagettftext($png_image, 25, 0, 150, 1220, $white, $font_path, $wrong4);


  //imagepng($png_image);
 imagepng($png_image, "img/".$id.".png");
  imagedestroy($png_image);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Use [`imagettfbbox()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php) to get the text dimensions, compare that to the widget size, iterate inserting line breaks as needed.

Comment: I have did it but now, I can see my all lines in one line